# Deinterlace a frame with ffmpeg 5.1

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, migration, frame, deprecated

I have been searching on the internet how to deinterlace a frame with Ffmpeg 5.1. Every solution I found are for old versions of Ffmpeg. Those solutions are not working for Ffmpeg 5.1 because of deprecated classes or functions that have been removed from the newest version. In version 2.1 of Ffmpeg we used to have :

```
int avpicture_deinterlace(AVPicture* dst,
const AVPicture * src,
enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt,
int width,
int height 
)
```

Now I'm looking to implement a similar function but with AVFrame instead

```
int avframe_deinterlace(AVFrame* dst
const AVFrame* interlacedFrame,
enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt,
int width,
int height 
)
```

But I don't know how to do it!
I've started to look at the documentation and it would take me weeks to implement it.
In the mean time I'll try to do it by myself but help would be appreciated.

I'm looking for how to deinterlace a frame programmatically with Ffmpeg 5.1. More specifically how to implement this function :

```
int avframe_deinterlace(AVFrame* dst
const AVFrame* interlacedFrame,
enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt,
int width,
int height 
)
```

Comment: You have to use a filter like yadif, bwdif...etc

Comment: I already know that, I'm asking for the details of the implementation. I wanna see the code.

Comment: What your old API snippets show is *not* a filter. See https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/filtering_video.c for a minimal example.

Comment: Thx, I think the exemple in your link answers my question